# Thick Bezier curves in SVG without artifacts

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I try to draw thick [Bezier lines](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/) (for a custom [Sankey diagram](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/)).
I use [SVG Paths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths), with Bezier curves in the form of `C x1 y1, x2 y2, x y`. I use `stroke` rather than `fill`, so that they have constant width (and can represent flows).

It works very well if the lines are thin or if the vertical difference is relatively low. However, if they are very thick, I get some nasty artifacts (looking like horns) - see the bottom right curve from the picture below:

[image]

Source: http://jsfiddle.net/stared/83jr5fub/

Is there a way to avoid artifacts, i.e.:

- ensure there is nothing on the left of `x1` or right of `x`,
- actual widths on the left and right match `stroke-width`?

Comment: I'm personally not getting any artifacts. Have you tried a different browser or machine?

Comment: @MonicaOlejniczak You mean on JSFiddle? The above is a screenshot (by artifacts I mean the "horns".) When it comes to browses - it looks for me the same on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: Maybe this fiddle will make it more clear what is happening : http://jsfiddle.net/83jr5fub/2/

Comment: @Kaiido I know what is happening (but thank you a lot for this example - stripes make it clearly visible!). My problem is how to avoid such behavior; I did try to use `fill` shapes but then their widths was visibly uneven (though maybe some tweaking would help). With `stroke` - I am thinking that maybe some mask would help.

Comment: dump of possible but untested solution : `stroke-linecap: rect` but this will add the stroke-width at start and ending points of your path. make a closed path and fill it. Be sure that your stroke-width is never more than the angle... I dont know how to clearly say that but just be sure the dashes in this fiddle never collapse : http://jsfiddle.net/83jr5fub/3/ And that's almost all of what I can think of. I don't think the mask would help since IMMind you'd need the closed path too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that he best solution in your case (with the given path), is to make your path closed, and use its fill property.

To do this, you'll have to make a `lineTo(0, strokeWidth)` at the end of your `BezierCurveTo`, and then to redraw the bezierCurve in the other way :

```js
var svg = d3.select("#chart");

var data = [
 {t: 5, dy: 10},
 {t: 5, dy: 20},
 {t: 5, dy: 40},
 {t: 20, dy: 10},
 {t: 20, dy: 20},
 {t: 20, dy: 40},
 {t: 50, dy: 10},
 {t: 50, dy: 20},
 {t: 50, dy: 40},
];

var ctrl = 10;
var dx = 40;
var spacing = 100;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();

svg
  .attr("width", 4 * spacing)
  .attr("height", 4 * spacing);

svg.selectAll("path")
  .data(data)
  .enter()
   .append("path")
    .attr("d", function (d, i) {
      var x1 = spacing + spacing * (i % 3);
      var y1 = spacing + spacing * Math.floor(i / 3);
      return "M" + x1 + "," + y1 +
      "c" + ctrl + "," + 0 +
      " " + (dx - ctrl) + "," + d.dy +
      " " + dx + "," + d.dy +
      // move down for the wanted width
      "l" + (0) + "," + (d.t) +
      // negate all values
      "c" + (ctrl * -1) + "," + 0 +
      " " + ((dx - ctrl) * -1) + "," + (d.dy * -1) +
      " " + (dx * -1) + "," + (d.dy * -1);
  })
  .style("fill", colors(0))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg id="chart"></svg>
```

And since an animation worth more than 10 thousand words here is one showing what was happening and why it can't be called a browser bug :

```css
@keyframes dash {
  from {
     stroke-dashoffset: -10%;
  }
   to {
     stroke-dashoffset: 90%;
  }
 }
@-webkit-keyframes dash {
  from {
     stroke-dashoffset: -10%;
  }
   to {
     stroke-dashoffset: 90%;
  }
 }
#dashed{
  animation : dash 12s linear infinite;
  }
```

```html
<svg height="200" width="200" id="chart" viewBox="290 260 100 100">
<path id="dashed" style="fill: none; stroke: rgb(31, 119, 180); stroke-width: 50; stroke-dasharray: 3, 3;" d="M300,300c10,0 30,40 40,40"></path>
<path style="fill: none; stroke: black;" d="M300,300c10,0 30,40 40,40">
</path></svg>
```

Comment: Very nice animation worth those 10 000 words

Comment: It is nice, but has one visual issue - lines get thinner in the middle, see e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/stared/ufms2tpe/ (actually, my initial approach was to use shapes, and only later I discovered that one can use very thick strokes). I tried to make controls uneven, but I couldn't find a good formula working across various thicknesses and `dy`s.

Comment: @PiotrMigdal,  I see... Actually the lines don't get "thinner" in the middle, it's just that their "weight" is always vertical (with vector 0,strokeWidth ). What you want would need to calculate the correct angle, and make the weight at this angle. This is what stroke does. But with your curve, it will lead to the oddities you got. I can't see a correct solution with this path...

Answer (score 1):

Kaiido gave an excellent and complete answer for why the SVG-path with thick stroke-width are displayed with artifacts and how to avoid this. I'll try to provide a bit more info that is specific to D3.js Sankey diagrams, as I was recently facing the same problem as Piotr Migdal.

### Original Sankey diagram code

(from Sankey.js in [this Sankey example](http://bl.ocks.org/cfergus/3956043), which is similar to the example Piotr Migdal mentioned)

```
  // regular forward node
  var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
      x1 = d.target.x,
      xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
      x2 = xi(curvature),
      x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
      y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
      y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
  return "M" + x0 + "," + y0
       + "C" + x2 + "," + y0
       + " " + x3 + "," + y1
       + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
```

### Modified code

```
  // regular forward node
  var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
      x1 = d.target.x,
      xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
      x2 = xi(curvature),
      x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
      y0 = d.source.y + d.sy,
      y1 = d.target.y + d.ty;
  return "M" + x0 + "," + y0
       + "C" + x2 + "," + y0
       + " " + x3 + "," + y1
       + " " + x1 + "," + y1
       // move down for the wanted width
       + "l" + 0  + "," + d.dy
       // draw another path below mirroring the top
       + "C" + x3 + "," + (y1 + d.dy)
       + " " + x2 + "," + (y0 + d.dy)
       + " " + x0 + "," + (y0 + d.dy);
```

Then you'll also need to change your css:

- stroke: none
- set fill color

and remove any D3 code that sets stroke-width of HTML elements.